# Why are functions not working in Codeigniter default controller?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a fresh install of codeigniter.  I am simply trying to use a function in my default controller like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $data = array(
           'title' => 'Welcome',
           'description' => 'Welcome Page'
        );

        $this->load->view('layouts/header',$data);  
        $this->load->view('home/home');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer',$data);
    }

    public function contact()
    {

        $data = array(
           'title' => 'Contact Us',
           'description' => 'Contact Page'
        );

        $this->load->view('layouts/header',$data);  
        $this->load->view('home/contact');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer',$data);
    }
}
```

I have removed index.php successfully using htaccess. Now when I go to example.com/welcome/contact it works, but not example.com/contact/.

Why is this, shouldn't this work by default without using routes?

Answer (score 6):

use route inside codeigniter, so you can rerwrite new uri for each of them

```
$route['contact'] = 'welcome/contact';
```

and don't forget about htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 4):

The "default controller" is only used when there are no URL segments. It only calls one method, and the default method of a controller is `index()`.

Generally, the first part of your URL maps to a controller:

This would invoke the `index` method of the `contact` controller:

> `http://example.com/contact`

This would invoke the `hello` method of the `contact` controller:

> `http://example.com/contact/hello`

This would invoke the `hello` method of the `contact` controller and pass `world` as the first argument:

> `http://example.com/contact/hello/world`

Read all about it in the user guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

You need a `contact` controller for this URL to work, or you can use [routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I am using, but still I have been redirected to default 404 page of CI

Answer (score 0):

`example.com/contact/` calls the Contact controller, and what you have is a method in the Welcome controller (which is your default controller, like @Madmartigan explained).